# Exponential of an outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix $A = uu^T$ which has size $10$x$10$ and $||u|| = 9$. I want to find $e^{At}$ in terms of $u$. I know that $e^{At}$ can written as:
\begin{equation}
e^{At} = P^{-1}e^{J}P
\end{equation}

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, its Jordan form $J$ is composed of blocks with size $1$. So, I can write $e^{J}$(diagonal matrix with $1$'s and $e^{-9t}$). What I struggle to do is that I can't find a closed form solution due to $P$ which is composed of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Hint: look at $A^2$

Comment: @user619894 thank you for the tip, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use user619894's hint. We know $A^{2} = uu^{T}uu^{T} = \|u\|^2 A$. Following this pattern, we observe that $A^3 = \|u\|^2 A^2 = \|u\|^{4}A$. In general, we can say that $A^{n} = \|u\|^{2(n-1)}A$ for $n \geq 1$. We now use the following formula for the matrix exponential:

$$e^{X} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!}X^{k}.$$

In our setting, this becomes:

$$I + A + \frac{\|u\|^2}{2!}A + \frac{\|u\|^4}{3!}A + \frac{\|u\|^6}{4!}A + \cdots$$

Factoring out $A$, we have:

$$I + A(1 + \frac{\|u\|^2}{2!} + \frac{\|u\|^4}{3!} + \frac{\|u\|^6}{4!} + \cdots)$$

Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: $t$ is missing.